# Bypassing SSO property on oVirt 4.0

Tags: domain-name-system, fqdn, ovirt, rhev

I have upgraded oVirt engine from 3.6 to 4.0, after the upgrade i could not access the webadmin portal, the welcome page displays this message:

```
The client is not authorized to request an authorization. It's required to access the system using FQDN.
```

After reading on oVirt 4.04 Release Notes i learned this was due to Single Sign-On using OAUTH2 protocol, ovirt requires me to access the engine with FQDN, unfortunately I'm managing my resources remotely with just one public IP and i don't own any domain name. how do i get around this issue?.
If it can be of any help, below is my oVirt engine setup summary

```
      Default SAN wipe after delete           : False
      Firewall manager                        : firewalld
      Update Firewall                         : True
      Host FQDN                               : ovirt
      Upgrade packages                        : True
      Engine database secured connection      : False
      Engine database host                    : localhost
      Engine database user name               : engine
      Engine database name                    : engine
      Engine database port                    : 5432
      Engine database host name validation    : False
      DWH database secured connection         : False
      DWH database host                       : localhost
      DWH database user name                  : ovirt_engine_history
      DWH database name                       : ovirt_engine_history
      DWH database port                       : 5432
      DWH database host name validation       : False
      Engine installation                     : True
      PKI organization                        : some_organization
      DWH installation                        : True
      Configure local DWH database            : True
      Engine Host FQDN                        : ovirt
      Configure Image I/O Proxy               : True
      Configure VMConsole Proxy               : True
      Configure WebSocket Proxy               : True
```

Comment: Have you tried to define some private FQDN via the hosts and client hosts file?

Comment: @dyasny can you please give a little more details/ how do i setup this FQDN with the hosts files?

Comment: This is very basic: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html

Comment: my bad, i thought /etc/hosts file is there only to resolve local IPs, thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: so, did it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no control over DNS you can improvise using local `/etc/hosts` files. A dirty-ish hack but should be effective enough to get things working

Answer (score 4):

You can specify an alternative FQDN simply by editing the **`SSO_ALTERNATE_ENGINE_FQDNS`** variable in `/etc/ovirt-engine/engine.conf.d/11-setup-sso.conf` on the oVirt Engine.

Then restart the engine daemon:

```
# systemctl restart ovirt-engine.service
```